# How to add Caret to a Form control?

Tags: c#, winforms

On the goal to learn how to create C# Form components. I decided to create a label which the text can be selected with caret showing the current selection position. Using the code below i successfully added the text with custom color and font. But the caret is not showing. I used `CreateCaret` and `ShowCaret` of `user32` to create and display the caret.

```
class MyCustomLabel : Control
{
    string[] lines;

    public MyCustomLabel ()
    {
        lines = new string[] {
             "public class MyApp {",
             "    System.Console.WriteLine(\"Hello,World\");",
             "}"};

        CreateCaret(Handle, IntPtr.Zero, 10, Height);
        ShowCaret(Handle);
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        StringFormat fmt = StringFormat.GenericTypographic;
        fmt.FormatFlags |= StringFormatFlags.MeasureTrailingSpaces;
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; ++i)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(lines[i], Font, new SolidBrush(this.ForeColor),
              0, Font.Height * i, StringFormat.GenericTypographic);

    }

    [DllImport("user32")]
    private extern static bool ShowCaret(IntPtr hwnd);
    [DllImport("user32")]
    private extern static int CreateCaret(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr hBitmap, int width, int height);
}
```

At first place i want to have the Caret displayed and it will be appreciate if there is an example with selection.

Comment: The Caret is created when the Control is entered - so override `OnEnter` or `OnGotFocus` - and [destroyed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-destroycaret) when the Control loses focus - then, override `OnLeave` or `OnLostFocus`. You should also [position it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setcaretpos), otherwise it will almost overlap the left (or right) border or your Control. The height should be set to the Font height. You have a lot more stuff to override.

Comment: The default caret is just a dull bar, so you may also want to work on that. To make that caret function on *something*, it's a different story.

Comment: @jimi thank's that works for selection have you any idea how to support it?